# Proper way to check if form is empty in Emberjs

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, ember.js

I am using HTML5 validation in my form which is like this,

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="project">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="span6">
            <div class="well well-small">
                <p style="text-align: center">
                    You can create a new Project by filling this simple form.
                </p>

                <p style="text-align: center"> Project Name should be minimum 10 characters & There's no limit on
                    Project Description.
                </p>
            </div>
            <form class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="projectname">Project Name: </label>

                    <div class="controls">
                        {{!view App.TextFieldEmpty}}
                        <input type="text" name="projectname" id="projectname" required title="Project Name is Required!" pattern="[A-z ]{10,}" placeholder="Enter Project Name"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="projectdesc">Project Description:</label>

                    <div class="controls">
                        <textarea rows="3" id="projectdesc" name="projectdesc" placeholder="Enter Project Desc"
                                  required="Description Required"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                        <button class="btn" {{action 'createNew'}}>Add Project</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

And here's what I have tried to do in App.js,

```
App.ProjectController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    actions : {
        createNew : function() {
            if (!("#project form.form-horizontal") === "") {
                App.Project.createNew();
            }
        }
    }
});

App.ProjectRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

});

App.Project.reopenClass({
    createNew : function() {

        dataString = {
            'projectname' : $("#projectname").val(),
            'projectdesc' : $("#projectdesc").val()
        };
        console.log('check');
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "http://ankur.local/users/createNewProject",
            data : dataString,
            dataType : "json",
            success : function(data) {
                console.log('success');
            }
        });
        return false;

    }
});
```

As you can see in the actions, I am trying to check if form is not empty then do a Ajax POST. But the problem I am encountering is even if the form is not empty, the button doesn't do anything.
Moreover, if I am including the whole form, it will check checkboxes as well? (I want to have one as well)

What I can do to make sure that user doesn't submit empty form?

Comment: Have you tested your `(!("#project form.form-horizontal") === "")` conditional? At first glance, I don't see how this could return true.

Comment: Yes I have tried it with empty form and a filled one as well

Comment: possible duplicate of [Form Validations in EmberJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14609303/form-validations-in-emberjs)

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a JS/jQuery question than an Ember one. You should look at the jQuery [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) function.

You should validate your form inputs in your view, where you can access the `<input` elements. Furthermore `(!("#project form.form-horizontal") === "")` is missing the jQuery selector `$`.

```
App.ProjectView = Ember.View.extend({
    actions : {
        createNew : function() {
            if (!(this.$("#projectname").val() === "")) {
                App.Project.createNew();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

There might be some other kinks in your code, it would be helpful if you could put together a jsFiddle - that way it makes it much easier for us to help you and you.

Comment: I was onto this solution actually but I was gonna check individual fields instead. Also I am getting this, `this.$ is not a function`

Comment: You will need to do this in your view, not the controller. Also this will only work for individual fields, you cannot check the entire form at once.

Comment: But actions has to be in the controller, no?

Comment: In the controller you will not have access to your view/template HTML. It depends on what you want to do. The guideline I follow is everything pertaining to the HTML goes into the view, actions on a lower level that belong to the underlying data (such as the `createNew` method in your model) go into the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I am going to answer my own question & it seems to be working.

Here's what I did:

```
App.ProjectController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    actions : {
        createNew : function(event) {
            $(":text, :file, :checkbox, select, textarea").each(function() {
                if ($(this).val() === "") {
                    alert("Empty Fields!!");
                } else {
                    App.Project.createNew();
                                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            });

        }
    }
});
```