# How to validate content of an <input> tag in EmberJS

Tags: ember.js

I've defined an input field in one of my Handlebars template as follows:

```
<input {{bind-attr value=stratName}}>
```

I didn't want to use this:

```
{{input value=stratName}}
```

because I want to run a validation function against user input before the new value is copyied to the model.

What's the easiest way to attach a validation function, triggered on focusOut, on the input tag?  I also want to keep the user from leaving the field until a valid input is detected?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Form Validations in EmberJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14609303/form-validations-in-emberjs)

Answer (score 0):

You could use https://github.com/dockyard/ember-validations and attach the validation to the field, and on blur execute the validation, complaining or refocusing if the validation fails.

Comment: Code example would be nice.